# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component - even when clearing interval

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing a strange issue.

I have a `Message` component that contains the following code:

```
const Message = (props) => {

    const [timeout, setTimerTimeout] = useState(null);
    const [someVar, setSomeVar] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimerTimeout(prevTimeout => {
            if (prevTimeout) {
                clearInterval(prevTimeout);
            }
            return setInterval(someFunc, 1000)
        });
    }, [someVar]);

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearInterval(timeout);
        };
    }, []);

    ...
}
```

Even though I'm clearing the interval in the return func of useEffect, I'm getting this message in the console (pointing to `Message` component):

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. 
This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. 
To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

When returning `null` instead of `setInterval(someFunc, 1000)`, the warning is gone (but of course this is not what I want, i just know that the interval is causing the problem).

I don't know what I am doing wrong and how to get rid of it.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second useEffect is only created once, when the component renders for the first time, and so the value it has for `timeout` is null. So it will clear null.

You don't need two effects though, you just need one. You can modify your first effect to include a teardown function, and to not need to save the timer id to state:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let id = setInterval(someFunc, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);
}, [someVar]);
```

Comment: I thought that the function in the seoncd useEffect will use the last timeout value. and your code ignoring the fact that an interval is already running and you don't cancel it. That is why i put a clearInterval before the set.

Comment: `your code ignoring the fact that an interval is already running and you don't cancel it. `  I did not ignore it, i rewrote it to use standard react practices. You were doing a lot of extra work for something which is supported out of the box. Each time an effect runs (due to someVar changing), it will run the previous effect's teardown function. So the intervals *will* be canceled, just like yours did. In addition, the teardown will be run when unmounting, which fixes your issue.

Comment: My mistake, you are right. the only problem with your solution is that `someFunc` is decreasing state variable by one, and when it is equal to 0, i want to cancel the interval. how can i achieve that?

Comment: I managed to solve it by doing this: `const intervalId = setInterval(() => timeoutFunc(intervalId), 1000);` and call clearInterval inside timeoutFunc on the given interval id. thanks!

Comment: Is someFunc defined inside the effect? If so, it has access to the id variable and can call clearInterval when some condition is met. `let id = setInterval(() => {
  setAThing((prev) => {
    if (prev === 1) {
      clearInterval(id);
    }
    return prev - 1;
  });
});`

Comment: What is the preferred way? to pass intervalId to timeoutFunc or to declare on timeoutFunc inside useEffect func?

Comment: If the function is unique to this effect and not needed elsewhere, i would move it inside the effect, so that related code can be found in the same place. If multiple things need to use the function (say, it's also called by an onClick), then it will need to be outside the effect.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanup function for your `useEffect` hook should be part of the same call that sets up the effect.

Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    () => setTimerTimeout(prevTimeout => {
        if (prevTimeout) {
            clearInterval(prevTimeout);
        }
        return setInterval(someFunc, 1000)
    });
    return () => clearInterval(timeout);
}, [someVar]);
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup

Comment: Why did you put setTimerTimeout in a function without calling it? the code inside the function will run?

Comment: This was just based exactly on the code you posted and giving you a solution that will remove the interval on unmount. The implementation of your interval and timer are up to you. I posted the link to the react docs so you can read up a little more on best practices with useEffect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a guard variable which cancels the async action (in this case a timer, or in another scenario a fetch request) if the component is unmounted prior to it's return.

```
const Message = (props) => {

  const [startInterval, setStartInterval] = useState(null);  

  useEffect(() => {

    let cancel = false;

    const intervalID = setInterval(() => { // run every second
      if (!cancel) {                       // but don't run if component unmounts
        someFunc();
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => {               // runs when component unmounts
      cancel = true;             // stop an already-running interval
      clearInterval(intervalID); // stop the interval generator
    });

  }, [startInterval]);

  ...

}
```

---

If you use `setSomeVar` to allow the user to manually stop the timer, e.g on a click event

```
const Message = (props) => {

  const [startInterval, setStartInterval] = useState(null);  
  const [stopInterval, setStopInterval] = useState(null);  

  useEffect(() => {

    let cancel = false;

    let intervalID;
    if (stopInterval && intervalID) {

      clearInterval(intervalID); // manually stop the interval generator

    } else {

      intervalID = setInterval(() => { // run every second
        if (!cancel) {                 // but don't run if component unmounts
          someFunc();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => {               // runs when component unmounts
      cancel = true;             // stop an already-running interval
      clearInterval(intervalID); // stop the interval generator
    });

  }, [startInterval, stopInterval]);

  ...

}
```